# Gradle fails to find my .jar on bintray

Tags: android, maven, jar, bintray

I have just added my library to my maven repository via Bintray but when I try to add the dependency in a project, Gradle fails to find the .jar.

```
Error:Could not find mylib.jar      (com.test.mylib:mylib:1.0.0).
Searched in the following locations:
https://dl.bintray.com/pseudo/maven/com/test/mylib/mylib/1.0.0/mylib-1.0.0.jar
```

The issue is simply the name of the jar since I have a mylib-1.0.0-sources.jar in my repository. So how can I change this path ?

Thanks.

Note : I have added the maven url in the build.gradle.

I followed this tutorial to upload my library :

https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/how-to-upload-library-to-jcenter-maven-central-as-dependency/en

My problem is at the end of part 5 when I add the dependency as follow :

```
repositories {
   maven {
       url 'https://dl.bintray.com/nuuneoi/maven/'
   }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.inthecheesefactory.thecheeselibrary:fb-like:0.9.3'
}
```

Comment: I can't follow ... what about changing the name of the jar in your build gradle ?

Comment: do you only have a source jar? why do you want gradle to treat it as a dependency?

Answer (score 0):

Please try

```
compile 'com.inthecheesefactory.thecheeselibrary:fb-like:0.9.3@aar'
```